# Since upgrading acer laptop to 22.04 external moniter is not recognized

Tags: upgrade, acer, external-monitor

I have been running Ubuntu on this acer AspireR laptop since I bought it. It has intel graphics so I have had 0 trouble until today when I upgraded to 22.04 now my external monitor says there is no signal and nothing I have tried (run from thumb drive, created new account, switched to xorg) has had any effect.
Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

This is rather a comment than an answer (I have not the required reputation for a comment):

On my Acer Nitro 5 with an Ubuntu 22.04 fresh install the external monitor is also not recognized, but only if I have the Intel driver enabled (`sudo prime-select intel`; command works with nvidia proprietary driver).
If I switch to the dedicated Nvidia card (`sudo prime-select nvidia`) the external monitor works fine.

As ChanganAuto points out in his comment, this doesn't mean there is a problem with the Intel driver (I assumed that at first) but can result from the hardware wiring.

If you also have 2 graphic cards, maybe Ubuntu changed to only using the Intel driver after the upgrade and this causes the issue.

Comment: *it's an issue with the Intel i915 driver* No. It's just thew way hardware is wired. In many laptops with hybrid graphics external monitors only work with the dGPU. It has nothing to do with the Intel driver.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks for your comment. I've updated my post to take that into account.